# Dynamics 365(9.0) in Unified Client Interface - How to enable Grid above New button and editable Form?

Tags: dynamics-crm, microsoft-dynamics, dynamics-365, dynamics-crm-365-v9, dynamics-crm-uci

In UCI not able see "New" button above grid and also editable Form for the same custom entity. I have given the required Security Roles. In classic form, I'm able to do all these things.

Answer (score 0):

Seems like there is a bug in the dynamics 365 UCI for desktop view.

Solution Steps are as follows:

1. Select Setting > Customizations > Customize the system
2. Select Entity from Components
3. In General Tab > Scroll down to "Outlook & Mobile"
4. **Leave unchecked checkbox "Read-only in mobile".**

[image]

Comment: I'm still struggling to get the plus button to show on the sub grid view - I understand why having Read Only in Mobile set would block it, but there seems to be something else also blocking the appearance of the button.

Comment: @Andrew-EversightLtd have you selected preferred security role for UCI app and it should have required permission to the entity ?